# Writing an array list to a text file, then reading it in table view issue

Tags: java, javafx

When I try to write an array list to a file, it works fine the first time. But each time when I restart the program, the first time I click on a button to write to the file, it duplicates the list.

For example, the first time I run the program and add the following object to the array list, then write to file, output on the file is:

```
Aaaaaa,aaaaaaa
```

If I restart the program, and then again do the same thing, the output is:

```
Bbbbbb,bbbbbbb
Aaaaaa,aaaaaaa
Aaaaaa,aaaaaaa
```

The third time:

```
Cccccc,cccccc
bbbbbb,bbbbbb
aaaaa,aaaa
aaaaa,aaaa
bbbbbb,bbbbbb
aaaaa,aaaa
aaaaa,aaaa
```

And so on. So far I have not been able to track down what causes this.

Here is the fxml controller:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets; 
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GUImembersController implements Initializable
{
private Member member;
private MemberList memberList = new MemberList();
private String filename = "MemberList.txt";
private MemberFile memberFile = new MemberFile(filename);

ObservableList<Member> members = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML private BorderPane memberPage = new BorderPane();

@FXML private Button btnAddMember,btnClearTextFields;

@FXML private TextField tfEnterMemberName,tfEnterMemberEmail;

@FXML private TableView<Member> memberTable;

@FXML private TableColumn<Member, String> tcMemberName,tcMemberEmail;




@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
{
    memberPage.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    memberPage.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

    tcMemberName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Member, String>("name"));
    tcMemberEmail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Member, String>("email"));

    try {
        memberTable.setItems(getList());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public ObservableList<Member> getList() throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException
{       
    MemberList memberLi = memberFile.readMemberTextFile();

    for (int i = 0; i < memberLi.size(); i++)
    {
        members.add(new Member(memberLi.getMember(i).getName(), memberLi.getMember(i).getEmail()));
    }       

    return members;     
}

@FXML
void addMember(ActionEvent event) throws ParseException, CloneNotSupportedException, IOException 
{
    String memberName = tfEnterMemberName.getText();
    String memberEmail = tfEnterMemberEmail.getText();
    member = new Member(memberName,memberEmail);
    memberList.addMemberToList(member);
    memberFile.writeMemberTextFile(memberList);

    clearTextFields(event);
}

@FXML 
void clearTextFields(ActionEvent event) 
{
    tfEnterMemberName.setText("");
    tfEnterMemberEmail.setText(""); 
}
}
```

Here is the class where I handle writting and reading from file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MemberFile {
private int sw = 0;
private File file;
private String filename = "MemberList.txt";

private MemberList currentMemberList = new MemberList();
private MemberList currentMembers = new MemberList();;
private MemberList memberList = new MemberList();

public MemberFile(String filename) {
    setFile(filename);
}

public void setFile(String filename) {
    file = new File(filename);
}

public File getFile() {
    return this.file;
}

public MemberList readMemberTextFile() throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
    Scanner input = null;

    try {
        input = new Scanner(file);
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] lineToken = line.split(",");
            lineNumber++;

            String memberName = lineToken[0].trim();
            String memberEmail = lineToken[1].trim();

            Member member = new Member(memberName, memberEmail);
            currentMemberList.addMemberToList(member);
        }
        return currentMemberList;
    }

    finally {
        input.close();
    }
}

public void writeMemberTextFile(MemberList memberList) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException, CloneNotSupportedException 
{       
    PrintWriter output = null;      

    switch(sw)
    {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("Reading from file");
        currentMembers = readMemberTextFile();

        for(int i = 0; i < currentMembers.size(); i++)
        {
            memberList.addMemberToList(currentMembers.getMember(i));                
        }

        currentMembers.clearMemberList();
        System.out.println(memberList.size());          

        sw = 1;     

    case 1:
        System.out.println("Writing to file");          
        System.out.println(memberList.size());

        output = new PrintWriter(file);

        for (int i = 0; i < memberList.size(); i++) 
        {
            output.println(memberList.getMember(i).getName() + "," + memberList.getMember(i).getEmail());
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();

        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Get rid of the switch statement in `writeMemberTextFile`, don't **read** in a method that writes. The entire method looks specious.

Comment: Missing `break` after `case 0`

Comment: @mrmcwolf Looks deliberate, if weird.